# Importing root certificates using keystore

Tags: ssl-certificate, keystore

I attempted to import AmazonRootCA*.cer into our webserver (Centos 7.7) cacert store running Coldfusion 2018 using the keystore tool. However I'm getting the following message and I'm not quite sure what it means

```
$ /mydisk/cf2018/jre/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias AmazonRootCA1 -file ~user1234/AmazonRootCA1.cer -keystore /mydisk/cf2018/jre/lib/security/cacerts
Enter keystore password:  
Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias <amazonrootca1>
Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  no
Certificate was not added to keystore
```

**How do I locate this system-wide CA keystore to ensure existing amazonroot certificates match the new one (If its new) by comparing signatures/expiration dates?**

**What is the "your own keystore"?**

**Will saying "yes" cause problems?**

Comment: you can use the 'list' argument to list the existing certificates. There are many tutorials on the web to help you with basic keytool commands such as https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html